# How to use a for loop to increment the nth-child selectors in this JQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a basic function to deal with mismatching heights of divs in a 2 column responsive layout.

I'm new to JavaScript and am struggling to understand how to increment the numerical characters in the following function.

The aim here is to reduce this down to a single variable, and achieve the body of the function in 2 lines instead of repeating it 3 times for each target div.

I think a template string could be used to increment the numbers in the variable name.

My best guess is that a for loop could be used to do this, but I'm unclear on how to write this.

```js
function equalImages() {
  var div1Height = $('.equal-height-wrap .wp-block-column:first-child .wp-block-group:nth-child(2)').height();
  $('.equal-height-wrap .wp-block-column:nth-child(2) > .wp-block-group:nth-child(2)').height(div1Height);
                    
  var div2Height = $('.equal-height-wrap .wp-block-column:first-child .wp-block-group:nth-child(3)').height();
  $('.equal-height-wrap .wp-block-column:nth-child(2) > .wp-block-group:nth-child(3)').height(div2Height);
                    
  var div3Height = $('.equal-height-wrap .wp-block-column:first-child .wp-block-group:nth-child(4)').height();
  $('.equal-height-wrap .wp-block-column:nth-child(2) > .wp-block-group:nth-child(4)').height(div3Height);

}

equalImages()

$(window).on('resize', function(){
  equalImages()
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just do it in a loop, and templated strings also help.

```
function equalImages() {
  for(var i=2;i<5;i++){
    var divHeight = $(`.equal-height-wrap .wp-block-column:first-child .wp-block-group:nth-child(${i})`).height();
    $(`.equal-height-wrap .wp-block-column:nth-child(2) > .wp-block-group:nth-child(${i})`).height(divHeight);
  }

}

equalImages()

$(window).on('resize', function(){
  equalImages()
});
```

Answer (score -1):

To address your original problem about correcting the heights of mismatching divs, it might be worth doing it with CSS rather than JavaScript. One easy solution may be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_equal_height.asp